# android installation and problem in addressing of SDK

Tags: android, sdk, installation

Accessing to android website in order to dowload SDK is blocked in my country!

One of programmers who live in other country is shared his Eclipse and SDK and says that you can use mine. He mentioned that after copy this on your computer go to `Help>Install new software` in Eclipse, then click on `Available Software Sites` link and in `Preference` window, from the left list cick on `Android` and set the SDK Location.

My problem is, in Preference page I don't have Android in the list.

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: sorry to here that android sdk downloading is blocked in your country

Comment: @Fred I second that, it's really a shame it's hard for me to even comprehend that situation, why would a country block their people from accessing free resources, that can help them to bring money into the country? I mean... not that Android is going to vastly affect a GDP or anything but technology is technology, that's a real bummer.

Comment: Thanks dear guys for Sympathy, unfortunately Google blocked my country not government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this URL to the list of software sites when you go to Help->Install new software there should be a text input to fill in there or an add button, hit the add button then hit the archive button if the Android ADT plugin, DDMS, and other integration tools were sent to you as a zip if not try to get them using this URL in the location box, you can name it whatever you want in the top box if you go this route (url to use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/).  After getting the plug-ins for eclipse installed it will ask you to restart go ahead and do that then you go to Window-Preferences and click on Android on the left and add your SDKs in there, then you should be good to go just try to build some of the sample apps and when you go to run it should prompt you with a pop-up where you can create a virtual machine and choose it's preferences then run it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi dear shaunhusain, the thing that you said is true. but I reject when I want to connect to network. because of this I downloaded a complete SDK to escape from this stage. It seems I can't use SDK :( Thanks again.